# is it possible to check if a char matches a list of possibilities?

Tags: java, if-statement, char

For example I know that when checking strings, you can do something like

```
if (string.matches("a|e|i|o|u|A|E|I|O|U" ) )
{
   // Then do this code.
}
```

but is there a way to check if a char matches a list of possibilities?
or do I have to check one by one, such as

```
if(char == a || char == e || char == i )
```

...ect.

Comment: Are you receiving the list of chars in some particular data structure? Otherwise, if you can, I'd go with @rgettman's answer where -1 means the char was not found in the string.

Comment: FYI, if you want to match a set of characters in a regex, there's a special notation for that: `string.matches("[aeiouAEIOU]")` which is more convenient and easier to read than `"a|e|i|o|u|A|E|I|O|U"`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do something similar when looking for a `char` in a `String`, by using the [`indexOf` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) to search the string.

```
if ("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(aChar) != -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

From the performance standpoint the optimum approach would be this:

```
private final BitSet matchChars = matchChars();

private BitSet matchChars() {
  final BitSet bs = new BitSet();
  final String matchString = "aeiouAEIOU";
  for (int i = 0; i < matchString.length(); i++)
     bs.set(matchString.charAt(i));
  return bs;
}

public boolean charMatches(char c) { return matchChars.get(c); }
```

Memory required for the approach is very modest even if you use the whole 16-bit range afforded by the `char` type: at most 8 KB.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a collection of chars that you want to check, and see if the collection contains the char in question. A HashSet is ideal here for O(1) look up time. (not that it matters, because the size is constant.)

```
private static final HashSet<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>();

//Initialize vowels hashSet to contain vowel characters
static{
    vowels.add('a');
    vowels.add('e');
    vowels.add('i');
    vowels.add('o');
    vowels.add('u');
    vowels.add('A');
    vowels.add('E');
    vowels.add('I');
    vowels.add('O');
    vowels.add('U');
}

public static boolean isVowel(Character c){
    return vowels.contains(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Back before we had Unicode, when the character set was only 128 characters (ASCII) or later 256 (ISO 8859-1), we would often just create an array of Booleans and use a lookup on the character code--very fast.  You could still do the same (an array of 65536 `boolean`s isn't all that big by today's memory standards), or something like

```
static boolean[] vowelSet = new boolean[128]; // all initialized to false by default

static {
    vowelSet['A'] = true;
    vowelSet['E'] = true;
    ...
    vowelSet['u'] = true;
}
```

and then to look up:

```
boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    return ch < 128 && vowelSet[ch];
}
```

I think that's still the approach I'd take if efficiency were extremely important.  Usually it isn't, so one of the other answers probably gives you more readable code.

Comment: An array of `long`s treated as bitfields is even smaller---and it's standard API to boot :)