# Alternative for if(something || somethingElse || somethingElse2 || somethingElse3 ...)

Tags: java, performance, design-patterns, syntax

I was thinking how to improve a part of my program but I would like to know if is there a "silver bullet" for this kind of cases. Is there any strategy to avoid big `if OR statements` like this?:

```
public boolean containsCharOfWord() {
        if (this.name.contains("b") || this.name.contains("a")
                || this.name.contains("c") || this.name.contains("t")
                || this.name.contains("e") || this.name.contains("r")
                || this.name.contains("i") || this.name.contains("a")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Universal replacement, or specifically for multiple `String.contains()`?

Comment: and make constants out of those char values.

Comment: For the specific case, it's quite obvious: regex. `name.matches(".*[abceirt].*")`.

Comment: Since you are checking twice if the `name` contains `a`, are you sure this is what you want and you're not looking for `return name.contains("bacteria");`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#matchesAnyOf(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
return CharMatcher.anyOf("bacteria").matchesAnyOf(name);
```

---

The fancy version would be

```
private static final CharMatcher VIRUS = CharMatcher.anyOf("bacteria").precomputed();

... return VIRUS.matchesAnyOf(name);
```

where the precomputation returns a faster matcher.

Comment: + public static final String BACTERIA = "bacteria";

Comment: Which is a minor detail, really. It could also be coming from a config file, database, or whatever.

Comment: I see they use a sorted `char[]` and binary search. That's quite efficient, but not as efficient as a [`BitSet`-backed solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555895/is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-char-matches-a-list-of-possiblities/27556584#27556584).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik There's a `precomputed` version using a `BitSet` (or something else if efficient), too.

Comment: Nice going... Guava covers every angle :)

Comment: I take my hat off for you mate! Very good answer, thank you and everyone else as well for your time

Comment: Naming the constant `VIRUS` was the touch that won my heart :)

Answer (score 3):

You should try using regex

```
public boolean containsCharOfWord() {
        return this.name.matches("(.*)([bacteria])(.*)");
}
```

Comment: @ZouZou sure, I have just copied code from OP without giving it much thought. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, removes a this.name.contains("a") because is duplicate

then you can try switch (JDK7)

```
    switch (name) {
    case "b":
      // do something
    case "a":
      // do something
    case "c":
      // do something
    case "t":
      // do something
    case "e":
      // do something
    case "r":
      // do something
    case "i":
      // do something
    }
```

Comment: Quite far from the posted requirement. Use a `for` loop and switch on `String.charAt()` to make a sensible answer.

Comment: What if name is "bacteria"? You only match a single character.

Comment: also you forgot about `break;` in each case

Answer (score 1):

You want to generalize over the series of characters that could be in the name:

```
public boolean containsAnyCharOfWord(String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (this.name.contains(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean containsCharOfWord() {
    return containsAnyCharOfWord("bacteri"); // don't need to check for 'a' twice
}
```

Comment: Working but slow (`O(m*n)`). And `String.valueOf` makes it pretty bad. Use `String#indexOf(char)`.

Comment: The OP wasn't asking for an optimal solution to this particular problem, he was asking "Is there any strategy to avoid big if OR statements like this?". That's what my answer addresses; anything else distracts from that by solving very different things.

Answer (score 1):

Without any external libraries: Use regex matching / pattern matching: I.e. "does my string match any of said characters"?

```
myString.matches(".*[bacteria].*")
```

Comment: Slow... compiling the regex every time.

Comment: OP asked about short code, not quick execution. One could alternatively pre-compile the pattern and just apply it. But depending on context, that might be more code than the problem warrants.

Comment: Yes, great stuff. Now it's just one edit shy of the solution in the comments.

Comment: Then why didn't you post yours as a solution? I didn't even read the comments up there.